# Extract data field from a byte data type (data is obtained using paramiko on python)

Tags: python, string, byte, paramiko

Reading nvram remotely from a Mac using SSH on `paramiko` package (python3), my readback data `stdout.read()` seems to have `bytes` as its data type.

```
data_readback= stdout.read()

print(type(data_readback)) #print data type of read back data
print(data_readback[0:60]) #printing first 60 characters of read back data
```

****Resultant output** **:
[image]

**Question:**

I would like to extract the data assigned to `boot-args` data field (ie..`debug=0x104c0c`) from this. How do I accomplish this? Note that the data `debug=0x104c0c` maybe different on each read back.

I did try to convert the data to string by using this next code but dont know how to extract either since it may require regex maybe.

```
boot_args_readback= stdout.read().decode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
data_as_bytes = b'boot-args\tdebug=0x104c0c\nnauto-boot\ttrue\nboot-volume\tEF57347C'

data_as_string = str(data_as_bytes, "ascii")

output = data_as_string.split()
entries = dict([(x, y) for x, y in zip(output[::2], output[1::2])])
print(entries['boot-args'])  # debug=0x104c0c
```